# Triger mouse event only on table row click

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this custom JavaFX table factory cell:

```
Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>()
        {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell<TableDataObj, Object>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(empty ? null : getString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }

                    private String getString()
                    {
                        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                    }
                };

                cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                    {
                        if (event.getClickCount() > 1)
                        {
                            EventsPanel ep = new EventsPanel();
                            TableDataObj person = (TableDataObj) table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                            ep.GeneralConfiguration(person);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return cell;
            }

        };
```

I noticed that when I select with mouse the table row I can trigger the event every where I click on the table. How I can fix the code to trigger the event only when I clic kon the table row.

Comment: Doesn't checking `if (! cell.isEmpty()) {...}` work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
private TableView<Person> myTable; // you have this Variable on your Class
if (myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
    /* Do your magic */
}
```

in your listener should work.

Comment: no - that's assuming the low-level event had triggered a semantic change _before_ it reached the listener. There's no guarantee about sequence of notification.